# How to remove line break when reading files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, line, newline, file-read, chomp

I'm trying to get rid of the brackets `[]` and the new line `\n` from being printed.

My code looks like:

```
name1 = File.readlines('first.txt').sample(1)
name2 = File.readlines('middle.txt').sample(1)
name3 = File.readlines('last.txt').sample(1)

name = print (name1.strip 
    print name2.strip 
    print name3.strip)

puts name
```

I would like the output to look like `JoshBobbyGreen`.
However, it looks like:

```
[\"Josh\\n\"][\"Bobby\\n\"][\"Green\\n\"]
```

I've tried using `.gsub`, `chomp` and `split` but maybe I'm using them wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a minor issue that causes the results you are experiencing.

when you use:

```
name1 = File.readlines('first.txt').sample(1)
```

The returned value **ISN'T** a String, but rather an Array with 1 random sample. i.e:

```
["Jhon"]
```

This is why you get the output `["Jhon"]` when using `print`.

Since you expect (and prefer) a string, try this instead:

```
name1 = File.readlines('first.txt').sample(1)[0]
name2 = File.readlines('middle.txt').sample(1)[0]
name3 = File.readlines('last.txt').sample(1)[0]
```

or:

```
name1 = File.readlines('first.txt').sample(1).pop
name2 = File.readlines('middle.txt').sample(1).pop
name3 = File.readlines('last.txt').sample(1).pop
```

or, **probably what you meant**, with no arguments, `sample` will return an object instead of an Array:

```
name1 = File.readlines('first.txt').sample
name2 = File.readlines('middle.txt').sample
name3 = File.readlines('last.txt').sample
```

Also, while printing, it would be better if you created one string to include all the spaces and formatting you wanted. i.e.:

```
name1 = File.readlines('first.txt').sample(1).pop
name2 = File.readlines('middle.txt').sample(1).pop
name3 = File.readlines('last.txt').sample(1).pop

puts "#{name1} #{name2} #{name3}."
# or
print "#{name1} #{name2} #{name3}."
```

Answer (score 33):

consider also optional chomp parameter in File.readlines

```rb
File.readlines("/path/to/file", chomp: true)
```

Answer (score 12):

puts adds a newline at the end of the output. print does not.
Use print. It may solve your issue. Also, use .strip.

```
"\tgoodbye\r\n".strip   #=> "goodbye"
```

Comment: i get this error `fullname.rb:36:in `strip': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
 from yahoo.rb:36:in `<main>'`

Answer (score 1):

If:

```
name1 = ["Josh\n"]
name2 = ["Bobby\n"]
name3 = ["Green\n"]
```

it's just:

```
puts [name1, name2, name3].map { |a| a.first.strip }.join('')
  #=> JoshBobbyGreen
```

Comment: I use `&:strip` exactly? because I get a `in map undefined method strip, for...`

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Do you get an exception running this? I'm sure the code's fine. Incidentally, `map(&:strip)` yields the same result as `map { |s| s.strip }`.

Comment: I wasn't sure if `&:strip` was a typo

Comment: but it says "in map: undefined method 'strip'"

Comment: That's very odd. `name1`, `name2` and `name3` are strings and the Class string certainly has a method `strip`.  The the code runs fine for me with Ruby v2.2 (and I don't think it could be a version issue).  Did you use my definitions `name1`, `name2` and `name3`? If not, I'd need to know the values of those variables to diagnose the problem.

Comment: the solution was written above, but thank you for your help :) I had no idea either, so I appreciate it.

Comment: It's because `Array#sample(n)` returns an array, there's no `strip` method in `Array`

Comment: @sbs, because of `map`, `String#strip` is invoked on each element of the array `[name1,name2,name3]`, which is a string.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, in OP's original question, `name1` is an Array.

Comment: It's not working because you're calling `a.first.strip`. In this example, `a` reference each element of the array, which is a string. You're then calling `a.first`, which there is no method `first` for string. Take out the `.first` and it'll work as expected.

Comment: @evanthegrayt, `a` references each element of  `[["Josh\n"], ["Bobby\n"],  ["Green\n"]]`, the first being `a = ["Josh\n"]`. `a.first #=> "Josh\n"`, so `a.first.strip #=> "Josh"`.

Comment: @Cary Ah, apologies, I totally missed that each element was an array itself.

Answer (score 0):

So as to avoid redundant `\n`'s I'd rather use `split`:

```
File.read('first.txt').split("\n") # double quotes are important!
```

So as to avoid getting array use `sample` method without arguments:

```
File.read('first.txt').split("\n").sample
```

Answer (score -1):

```
puts %w(first middle last).map { |e| IO.readlines("#{e}.txt").sample.strip }.join
```

Comment: If it works, a simple upvote to the answer would be appreciated. :)